# Flatness of $Hom_R(M,M)$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, flatness

The question is simple and clear: Let $M$ be an $R$-module, where $R$ is a commutative ring with an identity. When the $R$-module $Hom_R(M,M)$ is flat?

Comment: If $M$ is flat and finitely generated and $R$ is noetherian, then $M$ is locally free, so $Hom_R(M,M)$ is also locally free, hence flat.

Comment: If $M$ is reflexive (finitely generated over a Noetherian local ring), I believe the flatness of $End(M)$ implies $M$ is locally free by a theorem of Jothilingam. I do not remember it precisely, but can look up.

Comment: @oxeimon 's comment is based on Theorem 7.10 in Matsumura's Commutative Ring Theory Book. Can we find any other examples?